# Java bi-directional relationships with easy retrieval

Tags: java, mongodb, collections

What would be best have to have bidirectional relation ship optimized for retrieval. I am storing these objects in mongo database.

To optimize retrieval of shared content by second degree. I add reference to all the shared content by second degree friends inside the main contact

Overall I need to find shared content by second degree friends. Is there any Java collection or design that would be better in your opinion?

So far what I have :

```
Class person
String Name 
Set<Relation> Relations
List<Share> Shares

Class Relation
String fromIdOfPerdon
String toIdOfPerson

Class Share
String sharedObjectid
Set<String> shared by
```

Comment: It seems to me like what you would need is a graph database, not a document database.

Comment: Yes i though about neo4j, but its licence is not clear and i dont want to use a very niche product for which finding support/resources maybe difficult in future

Comment: Then at least use a relational database which allows you to do a self-join on Relation to get 2nd degree relations. A document database is pretty much the worst tool for queries like this.